# How to delete files in Azure kudu via VSTS after the deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How to delete files in Azure kudu after the deployment ? I wrote some Powershell script using Azure app service deploy task after the deployment using post deployment action step but I couldn't able to delete the files.
I have **simple-test.log** and **simeple.txt** files exist in azure kudu.Please help me to solve this issue.
Script:

```
if((Test-Path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot')) 
{
   rm simple*   
   Write-Host "Simple log file is exist,removed"
}
```

KUDU Log:

[KUDU LOG FILES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9hJM.png)

[Deployment Log Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JggU6.png)

Answer (score 0):

using kudu you would need to put it under `site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions`. then kudu will run it after every deployment automatically. All the ps1, bat, cmd under that directory would be run by kuku

you can also put it to a custom directory, but you'd need to tell kudu where to get it by setting this setting: `SCM_POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTIONS_PATH`.

Reading: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks

Comment: I can see the above path till tools (site\deployments\tools) after that I have created Postdeploymentactions folder and under that folder created .ps1 file with the content as if((Test-Path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot')) { rm simple*
Write-Host "Simple log file is exist,removed" } but that didn't work.Please help me if I miss anything.

Comment: I see logs but I don't understand what log says.Multiple logs I can see today.PFA for the same and help me.

Comment: I don't see any files under deployment log folder.

Comment: Please help is there any other way to delete files in kudu.

Comment: i dont really understand, if you dont have logs in deployment, means there was no deployments, means anything deployment related didnt work